# Tryng to filter a array of objects returning filled values

Tags: javascript

im tryng to filter my array of objects so i get only objects that have filled properties, but for some reason i get undefined.

This is how the array looks like

[image]

this my filter function

```
var newArray = $scope.informacoesNutricionais.propriedadesNutricionais.obrigatorias.filter(function (obj){ return !!obj.quantityContained});
```

Comment: Add a code snippet instead of an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking if the `quantityContained` contains something that isn't falsy.

Firstly, doing this with boolean operators isn't the best approach, since if `quantityContained` was `0`, this would still return false, and that item wouldn't be returned. Which I'm guessing is what you want to happen anyway, but it's still abusing the functionality and shouldn't be done.

Not sure why you're getting undefined as I can run something similar:

`var a = {arr:[{a:"a"}, {a:null}, {a:null}, {a:null}]}`

```
a.arr.filter(function(obj){return !!obj.a})
[{…}]
    0: {a: "a"}
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

Or better:

`a.arr.filter(function(obj){return obj.a !== null})`

Both return the same thing.

Use `obj !== null`, see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, in the end my function was fine, !! worked to check if the property was filled, not sure why i had undefined, maybe it was cache haha

Answer (score -1):

```
var newArray = $scope.informacoesNutricionais.propriedadesNutricionais.obrigatorias.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.quantityContained != null;
});
```

Please add a code snippet instead of an image next time as it will be easier for us to help you.